# image2gif writeGif failing to produce a GIF file (everything else above the last line works)

Tags: python, gif

I wrote the code below to convert several jpg images into a gif file

```
from images2gif import writeGif
from PIL import Image
import os
file_names = ['f14.jpg', 'f22.jpg','f14.jpg']
images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in file_names]
size = (600,350)
for im in images:
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)


writeGif('filename.gif', images, duration=0.1, repeat=True, dither=False,      nq=0, subRectangles=True, dispose=None)
```

```
writeGif('tunnelswirl.gif',images,0.005)
```

I run this code line by line and i noticed it was only in the very last line (writeGif) that it stops working. 
I also tried the writeGif below the longer writeGif instead (the shorter one)

Not sure why it doesnt work...

this is what i get in result of running the code

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e95e1efd1933> in <module>()
  9 
 10 
---> 11 writeGif('filename.gif', images, duration=0.1, repeat=True, dither=False,      nq=0, subRectangles=True, dispose=None)

C:\Users\seongwoo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\images2gif\images2gif.pyc in writeGif(filename, images, duration, repeat, dither, nq, subRectangles, dispose)
569     # Check subrectangles
570     if subRectangles:
--> 571         images, xy, images_info = gifWriter.handleSubRectangles(images, subRectangles)
572         defaultDispose = 1 # Leave image in place
573     else:

C:\Users\seongwoo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\images2gif\images2gif.pyc in handleSubRectangles(self, images, subRectangles)
293 
294             # Determine the sub rectangles
--> 295             images, xy = self.getSubRectangles(images)
296 
297         # Done

C:\Users\seongwoo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\images2gif\images2gif.pyc in getSubRectangles(self, ims)
330 
331             # Get difference, sum over colors
--> 332             diff = np.abs(im-prev)
333             if diff.ndim==3:
334                 diff = diff.sum(2)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (350,526,3) (350,525,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

The dimensions of each frame have to be identical for this to work, looks like one of yours is 350x526 and another is 350x525, which won't work.

Make sure your JPEGs are exactly the same size.